# Allocating more resource into task no impact on overall duration of project, Why?

Tags: ms-project

I'm a beginner. In my project, I added some resource into 2 tasks. The tasks' combined duration changed from 6 weeks to 2 weeks, but there was no impact on the overall duration of the project. Is there anyone who can explain the reason behind this?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of answering a homework question, the answer is your network path and the way tasks are sequenced.  Reducing the duration of a single task may or may not affect the total project duration depending on the degree of slack between that task's predecessor and successor.  If, at the time you reduced the duration, that task is on the critical path, then you will see a reduction in total duration assuming your network logic is sound.  If not, then you are just playing with slack.

Another cause might be a date constraint you have on a successor task.  For example, if your reduced duration task is on the critical path, however a successor task has a "must start on" constraint date, then your total duration will not decrease because you will create an arbitrary lag before that offending successor task.